# How to add a link within a .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a .click function to switch out text based on menu clicks. (example:http://jsfiddle.net/3r9hcz3z/) It works great except that I am still pretty new to Jquery & I can't figure out how to add a link inside of on one of the .html() menu items.

Any help would be awesome. I know that there is a way to do it within the Jquery but just can't find the right coding. Thanks!

```
$('#menuone').click(function(){
$('#title').text("ONE");
$('#text').html("This is text & where I would like to be able to add a link");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#text').html("<a href='someUrl'>Link</a>");
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thank you! I am so dumb, I was using " instead of ' around the url.

Answer (score 0):

one clean way to do this is to add a class to your anchor, and then set its href attribute through .attr:

```
$('.a_class').attr('href','http://example.com');
```